# Duplicate MySQL database via SSH

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, copy

Let's say that I have `database1` and `database2`.

`database1` - contains data

`database2` - is empty.

---

I want to copy all data from `database1` to `database2` via SSH - duplicate `database1`.

What command should I use?

---

I have tried

```
mysqldump -u user -p database1 > database1.sql
Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

Comment: Googling `mysql duplicate database` gives me everything necessary, e.g. http://www.rubyrobot.org/article/duplicate-a-mysql-database

Comment: The error you're getting indicates that you've submitted the wrong password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will copy database from S1 to S2

```
mysqldump --opt <database> | gzip -c | ssh user@wherever 'cat > /tmp/yourfile.sql.gz'
```

Unzip file

```
gunzip /tmp/yourfile.sql.gz
```

Next you'll have to import on S2

```
mysql -h<host> -u<user> -p<password> < /tmp/yourfile.sql
```

enjoy

Comment: What is "cat"? Should I replace it or what?

Comment: `cat` is a linux command for display on screen content of a file (try to read manuals: `man cat` )

Comment: basically there is no command to duplicate a database on separate servers. this action is made from several commands.

Answer (score 7):

Duplicate a MySQL database over SSH in just one command:

```
mysqldump -u <local-user> -p <local-db> | gzip | ssh user@hostname \
  "gunzip | mysql -u <remote-user> -p<password> <remote-db>"
```

Note that you must create the remote database first.

More advanced version:

```
mysqldump -u <local-user> -p <local-db> | xz | pv -W | ssh user@hostname \
"tee remote-dump.sql.xz | unxz | mysql -u <remote-user> -p<password> <remote-db>"
```

The advanced version:

- has better compression using `xz`/`unxz` (Though take care that compression speed doesn't become a bottleneck - if `xz` is at 100% CPU then it has probably become a bottleneck and you might be better off with `gzip`)
- shows a progress indicator using `pv`
- saves a copy of the dump using `tee`

Only one problem I haven't solved is how to avoid specifying the password in the remote command. It would be really nice to be able to enter this password interactively on the command line – if anyone knows how, please chime in.

Comment: One way to handle remote password is by using a option file on the remote server e.g. in ~/.my.cnf (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

Comment: I think that the gzip/xz, etc, unnecessarily complicate this, and, you may not benefit from compression depending on circumstances. I use "ssh -C" if I think compression's needed. Here's the barebones version that I typically use:

`$ ssh remotehost mysql -e "'create database dbname'"`

`$ mysqldump dbname | ssh remotehost mysql dbname`

Note that the silly double quotes are needed, one pair for each host involved. Also note that I have the needed bits in my `~/.my.cnf` file to not require putting username/passwd on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following 2 comands:

```
mysqldump -u customers -p customers > customers.dump



mysql -u new_customers -p new_customers < customers.dump
```

(you may get access denied because you can not write to the directory so you may have to change directory using `cd`)

source: http://support.tigertech.net/mysql-duplicate

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is to **ssh** into server from which you want to duplicate or copy the database to another server.

The command which worked for me was:

```
mysqldump -u <database-user> -p<database-password> <database-name> | xz | ssh <target-ssh-username>@<target-hostname> \ "tee remote-dump.sql.xz | unxz | mysql -u <target-database-user> -p<target-database-password> <target-database-name>"
```

***Note:-*** you can use .cnf file to store username and password of the database. Because my execution was small, I didn't used it.

**Link for doing that**: *https://www.techiecorner.com/1619/how-to-setup-mysqldump-without-password-in-cronjob/*

After entering your command. It will prompt you for

```
**The authenticity of host 'w01b3a99.kasserver.com (85.13.164.141)' can't be established.**

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

**type yes**

Then it will prompt you to enter

```
*target-user@target-hostname* ssh password
```

**Enter the password of `target-user` **password****

It will be silent execution running. After some time your command execution will be completed.

I haven't used `pv -W` because I was using the ***Cloudways Server***. `pv` wasn't installed already. They don't allow root access to install any package.